# Complex query can't pick index in MySQL (8.0.29)

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have indexed the where clause column still not sure why the query didn't pick it up. If anyone knows the reason and if there is any possibility please suggest some.

Query:

```
select 
  t.seq_no, 
  t.property_id, 
  ifnull(s.property_count, 0) property_count

from 
  (
    select 
      '1' seq_no, 
      '109363' property_id, 
      'Basecoworks' as property_name
  ) t 
  left outer join (
    select 
      s.seq_no, 
      s.property_id, 
      s.property_name, 
      count(s.property_id) property_count 
    from 
      s_fl s 
    where 
      s.created_at between '2022-09-17 00:00:00' 
      and '2022-10-17 10:31:21' 
    group by 
      s.seq_no, 
      s.property_id, 
      s.property_name
  ) s on s.seq_no = t.seq_no 
order by 
  t.seq_no;
```

Explain plan:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: PRIMARY
        table: <derived2>
   partitions: NULL
         type: system
possible_keys: NULL
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 1
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: NULL
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: PRIMARY
        table: <derived3>
   partitions: NULL
         type: ref
possible_keys: <auto_key0>
          key: <auto_key0>
      key_len: 4
          ref: const
         rows: 10
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using where
*************************** 3. row ***************************
           id: 3
  select_type: DERIVED
        table: s
   partitions: NULL
         type: ALL
possible_keys: created_at
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 55988164
     filtered: 50.00
        Extra: Using where; Using temporary
*************************** 4. row ***************************
           id: 2
  select_type: DERIVED
        table: NULL
   partitions: NULL
         type: NULL
possible_keys: NULL
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: NULL
     filtered: NULL
        Extra: No tables used

Table structure:

*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: app
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `s_fl` (
  `funnel_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `app_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `platform` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `app_version_id` int NOT NULL,
  `seq_no` int NOT NULL,
  `property_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `property_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `property_type` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `asi` bigint NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `capture_time_relative` decimal(15,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_event_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_event_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_message_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_message_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_tag_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_tag_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_crash` tinyint DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_anr` tinyint DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_ragetap` tinyint DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_error_type_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_error_type` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `screen_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `screen_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_screen_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_screen_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_task_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `ue_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`asi`,`seq_no`,`created_at`,`app_version_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `unique_asi_seq_no` (`asi`,`seq_no`),
  KEY `seq_no_date` (`seq_no`,`created_at`),
  KEY `last_ids` (`last_screen_id`,`last_event_id`),
  KEY `created_at` (`created_at`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

It's taking a long time I don't know where to modify it to improve the performance. does this have any possible options to make it optimize?

Sample data

```
+--------+-------------+----------------+
| seq_no | property_id | property_count |
+--------+-------------+----------------+
| 1      | 14236       |       07452475 |
+--------+-------------+----------------+
```

s table explain plan

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: s
   partitions: NULL
         type: ALL
possible_keys: created_at
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 54389573
     filtered: 50.00
        Extra: Using where; Using temporary
```

Comment: Provide complete CREATE TABLE. Provide sample data as INSERT INTO.

Comment: Provide execution plan for subquery `s` only - the rest of the query cannot use indices.

Comment: ok let me update

Comment: PS. `FROM (const) LEFT JOIN (subquery)` makes no sense - you may remove outer query completely and use subquery in the expression for `property_count` output column.

Comment: hi @Akina i have updated the s table execution plan

Comment: Try to create composite indices `(created_at, seq_no, property_id, property_name)` and `(seq_no, property_id, property_name, created_at)`. Test does one of them is used, and if you see an improvement then then store it.

Comment: Tell what is (approximately): #1 - the amount of groups with different `(seq_no, property_id, property_name)`; #2 - the percent of total rows amount which matches `WHERE created_at between '2022-09-17 00:00:00' and '2022-10-17 10:31:21'`. Tell does different `property_name` values for the same `property_id` value exists.

Comment: so can i use this composite index (seq_no, property_id, property_name, created_at) , what if i changed the order in the composite index for the group by column based on cardinality does it will affect the index performance or it will be good for the query? and you early said some of that makes no sense so is there any other way to omit or it's ok ? @Akina

Comment: and can I rewrite the above From table into the where clause? does it will affect the data or it will optimize the query while indexing? like where seq_no=1 property_id= .. .

Comment: *what if i changed the order in the composite index for the group by column based on cardinality does it will affect the index performance* You may reorder columns. But store the columns included into GROUP BY expression adjacent, do not place `created_at` between them. Both possible variants are provided above. *you early said some of* Until the subquery is optimized do not take care about it.

Comment: *and can I rewrite the above From table into the where clause?* If you have no rows which matches these values then your query will produce one row with zero in `property_count`. If you'd move these values to WHERE and there is no matches then the query won't return a row. Is it safe for you?

Comment: nah Nah .. I want the same output that the above query gives.

Comment: What's with the leading zero??  `07452475`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
PRIMARY KEY (`asi`,`seq_no`,`created_at`,`app_version_id`),
UNIQUE KEY `unique_asi_seq_no` (`asi`,`seq_no`),
...
INDEX(created_at)
```

-->

```
PRIMARY KEY (`asi`,`seq_no`),
INDEX(created_at, seq_no, property_id, property_name)
```

Turn this into a WHERE clause:

```
SELECT  '1' seq_no, '109363' property_id, 'Basecoworks' as property_name
```

Then have

```
INDEX(seq_no, property_id, property_name, created_at)
```

The `GROUP BY` has 3 columns, but then `JOINs` on only one of them.  Does this mean that `seq_no` uniquely represents one property?  If so, several other things are 'wrong'.

If `property_id` is `NOT NULL`, then use `COUNT(*)` instead of `count(s.property_id)`